# DataState.ordinal()' on a null object reference

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception

I get null on object reference. I have a default value set(not sure if this has an effect). My DataState is in a Arraylist which is shown in a Recyclerview. Datastate is changed when a button is clicked and reflect on a textview.

My datestate class:

```
enum class DataState {

    Unselected,
    Success,    
    Failure
}
```

My Arraylist:

```
class Tripsheetlist (var videos: ArrayList<DataModel>)


class DataModel(
    var Tripsheet: Int,
    var WOrder: Int,
    var DElNote: Int,
    var name: String,
    var Weight: Int,
    var tvdone: String,
    var Drivers: String,
    var state: DataState = DataState.Unselected

    )
```

My Adapter:

```
if ( rowPos  != 0){
            val modal =  tripsheetlist.videos[rowPos -1]

            holder.txttvdone.apply {
                setBackgroundResource(when (modal.state) {
                    DataState.Unselected -> android.R.color.transparent
                    DataState.Success -> R.color.green
                    DataState.Failure -> R.color.orange
                })
                text = when (modal.state) {
                    DataState.Unselected -> ""
                    DataState.Success -> "✓"
                    DataState.Failure -> "x"
                    //this is where I add code to export data through api maybe add it in the datastate set where it is success and Failure
                }
            }

            holder.apply {
                txtbutton1.setOnClickListener {
                    Log.e("Clicked", "Successful delivery")
                    //this is where I add code to export data through api
                    modal.state = DataState.Success
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                txtbutton2.setOnClickListener {
                    Log.e("Clicked", "Exception on delivery")

                    modal.state = DataState.Failure
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }}
```

I get the error on the line `setBackgroundResource(when (modal.state) {`

Error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dispatch.tripsheet, PID: 12935
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.dispatch.tripsheet.DataState.ordinal()' on a null object reference
        at com.dispatch.tripsheet.TableViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TableViewAdapter.kt:162)
        at com.dispatch.tripsheet.TableViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TableViewAdapter.kt:12)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
```

Below will be my full adapter and Main class.
Adapter:

```
package com.dispatch.tripsheet

    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.*
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.table_list_item.view.*


class TableViewAdapter(
    var tripsheetlist: Tripsheetlist,
    val driver: String,
    var tvHeader: TextView,
    val spnDriver: Spinner,
    var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TableViewAdapter.RowViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RowViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.table_list_item, parent, false)

        var i: Int = 0
        var totT: Int = 1
        var a: Int = 0
        var b: Int = 0
        var c: Int = 0
        var l: Int = tripsheetlist.videos.size -1

        while (i <= l){

            if (driver == tripsheetlist.videos[i].Drivers) {

                if (a == 0){
                    a = tripsheetlist.videos[i].Tripsheet}

                totT = totT

                if(a != tripsheetlist.videos[i].Tripsheet) {

                    if (b == 0){
                        b = tripsheetlist.videos[i].Tripsheet}

                    if ( totT != 3){
                        totT = 2}

                    if(b != tripsheetlist.videos[i].Tripsheet) {
                        c = tripsheetlist.videos[i].Tripsheet
                        totT = 3

                    }
                }
            }
            i++
        }
        when (totT)
        {
            1 -> tvHeader.setText("Vulcan Steel Trip Sheet: " +a)
            2-> tvHeader.setText("Vulcan Steel Trip Sheet: " + a + " & " + b )
            3-> tvHeader.setText("Vulcan Steel Trip Sheet: " + a + " & " + b + " & " + c)

            else -> tvHeader.setText("Vulcan Steel Trip Sheets")
        }


       
        var h =0
//            val driverList = tripsheetlist?.videos.distinctBy { it.Drivers }         
//            while (h <= driverList.size){
//                adapter.add(driverList[h].Drivers.toString())
//                h++
//            }


        //used for testing until we have driver data
        while (h <= 4){
            adapter.add("driverList[h].Drivers.toString()"+h)
            h++
        }

        spnDriver.adapter = adapter



        return RowViewHolder(itemView) }

    private  fun updateData(data: ArrayList<DataModel>) {
        tripsheetlist.videos = data

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int { return tripsheetlist.videos.size + 1 // one more to add header row
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RowViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val rowPos = holder.adapterPosition

        if (rowPos == 0) {
            holder.itemView.apply {
                setHeaderBg(txtWOrder)
                setHeaderBg(txtDElNote)
                setHeaderBg(txtCompany)
                setHeaderBg(txtWeight)
                setHeaderBg(txttvdone)

                txtWOrder.text = "WOrder"
                txtDElNote.text = "DElNote"
                txtCompany.text = "Compan"
                txtWeight.text = "Weight"
                txttvdone.text = "?"
            }
        } else {
            val modal = tripsheetlist.videos[rowPos -1]

            holder.itemView.apply {
                setContentBg(txtWOrder)
                setContentBg(txtDElNote)
                setContentBg(txtCompany)
                setContentBg(txtWeight)

                txtWOrder.text = modal.WOrder.toString()
                txtDElNote.text = modal.DElNote.toString()
                txtCompany.text = modal.name //company
                txtWeight.text = modal.Weight.toString()


//                  used when we have driver data
//                if (modal.Drivers == driver) {
//                    txtWOrder.text = modal.WOrder.toString()
//                    txtDElNote.text = modal.DElNote.toString()
//                    txtCompany.text = modal.name
//                    txtWeight.text = modal.Weight.toString()
//
//                }
            }
        }

        //used for testing to look in concsole for responeses -  all return null
//        println(tripsheetlist.videos[rowPos  ].name) //name needs to be chagned to company
//        println("where we need to see the state")
//        println("-1")
//        println(tripsheetlist.videos[rowPos  ].state)
//        println("0")
//        println(tripsheetlist.videos[0].state)
//        println("+1")
//        println(tripsheetlist.videos[1 ].state)
 var p = tripsheetlist.videos[1].state
        println("state")
        println(p)



        if ( rowPos  != 0){
            val modal =  tripsheetlist.videos[rowPos -1]

            holder.txttvdone.apply {
                setBackgroundResource(when (modal.state) {
                    DataState.Unselected -> android.R.color.transparent
                    DataState.Success -> R.color.green
                    DataState.Failure -> R.color.orange
                })
                text = when (modal.state) {
                    DataState.Unselected -> ""
                    DataState.Success -> "✓"
                    DataState.Failure -> "x"
                    //this is where I add code to export data through api maybe add it in the datastate set where it is success and Failure
                }
            }

            holder.apply {
                txtbutton1.setOnClickListener {
                    Log.e("Clicked", "Successful delivery")
                    //this is where I add code to export data through api
                    modal.state = DataState.Success
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                txtbutton2.setOnClickListener {
                    Log.e("Clicked", "Exception on delivery")

                    modal.state = DataState.Failure
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }}


    }
     class RowViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

         val txttvdone:TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txttvdone)
         val txtbutton1:Button = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.txtbutton1)
         val txtbutton2:Button = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.txtbutton2)
     }



    private fun setHeaderBg(view: View) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg)
    }

    private fun setContentBg(view: View) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg)
    }

}
```

Main class:

```
package com.dispatch.tripsheet


import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerViewTripsheetlist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val spnDriver: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spnDriver)

        var adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

        fetchJson( adapter, spnDriver)

    }
    private fun fetchJson(adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>, spnDriver: Spinner){

        println("Attempting to Fetch JSON")

        val url = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/youtube/home_feed"
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed to execute request")            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                println(body)

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                val tripsheetlist = gson.fromJson(body, Tripsheetlist::class.java)

                //remove the following later
                tripsheetlist.videos.apply {
                    add(DataModel(190617, 182832, 1, "100",20, "Delivery not done",""))
                    add(DataModel(190616, 182833, 2, "100",10, "Exceptions",""))
                    add(DataModel(190616, 182832, 3, "100",100, "50%",""))
                }
                
                    weightsum(tvTotalweight, tripsheetlist)
                    totaldelNotes(tvTotaldelv,tripsheetlist)
                
                var driver : String = Spinner(tripsheetlist, adapter)

                runOnUiThread {
                    recyclerViewTripsheetlist.adapter = TableViewAdapter(tripsheetlist, driver, tvHeader, spnDriver, adapter)
                }
            }
        })
    }


    private fun Spinner(tripsheetlist: Tripsheetlist, adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>): String {


        var driver : String = ""
        var item : String = ""
        var rowTot : Int = tripsheetlist?.videos.size

        spnDriver.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                var rowPos : Int = 0
                while (rowPos != rowTot){
                    //check which one of the following works

                  //  item  = tripsheetlist.videos[p2].Drivers.toString()
                    item  = p2.toString()
                    rowPos = rowTot
                }
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Driver $item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                driver = item
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                driver = ""
                //empty
            }
        }
        return driver
    }

    private fun totaldelNotes(tvTotaldelv: TextView, tripsheetlist: Tripsheetlist) {

       var totnotes :Int = tripsheetlist.videos.size
        tvTotaldelv.setText("Total Delivery Notes: " +totnotes) }

    private fun weightsum(tvTotalweight: TextView, tripsheetlist: Tripsheetlist) {
        var totweight: Int = 0
        var sum: Int = 0

        for (i in 0 until tripsheetlist.videos.size) {
            sum +=  tripsheetlist.videos[i].Weight }

        totweight = sum
        tvTotalweight.setText("Total Weight: " + totweight + "kg")
    }

//not used
    fun limitDropDownHeight(spinner: Spinner){
        val popup = Spinner::class.java.getDeclaredField( "mPopup")
        popup.isAccessible = true
        val popupWindow = popup.get(spinner)as ListPopupWindow
        popupWindow.height = (200 * resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the object that is null? From your last line you make it sound like it is `modal`, yet the explanation on top makes it sound like it is `state` that is null. Also where does the ordinal() call from the title come into play? Maybe add the Exception to the question.

Comment: How is `videos` in the `Tripsheetlist` populated? Is it from an API / from Java? It looks like the list might contain null values

Comment: @Joffrey So the list is populated through JSON. There are some null values in the array. But can this affect the state which is only affected by the button. Button is being altered by each data row. Rather just added to each row. There is a set click listener on the button to change the state.

Comment: @somethingsomething I have added to exception to better show the error.

Comment: idk how you actually create your adapter since you didn't share the full adapter , but check this part `holder.txttvdone` this code is probably return `null` object

Comment: @MuhammadRioPermana I added my full adapter and main. State is returning null. I did some test with - `println(tripsheetlist.videos[1 ].state)`